# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10 selenium programming

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is my code.

```
List<WebElement> tst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*@id='container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div"));




         System.out.println(tst.size());


         Thread.sleep(2000);
         for (int i = 1; i<=tst.size(); i=i+1)
            {

                System.out.println(tst.get(i).getText());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
```

But getting below error. Kindly help me please to resolve

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at Samples.sample2.main(sample2.java:42)
```

Comment: How is this at all related to java**script**?

Comment: Read some basics of array index. and java It is clearly saying the index is out of bound. else use for each loop..to avoid theses issues. There are many ways you can iterate over list

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand this is a java code and not a javascript code. On the other hand, you are trying to access an element with the index 10, but the index of the last element of this list is 9 since the indexes in a java list start at 0 (0 to 9). You have to loop from 0 to tst.size()-1:

```
List<WebElement> tst = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*@id='container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div"));
   System.out.println(tst.size());
           Thread.sleep(2000);
           for(int i=0;i<=tst.size()-1;i++)
           {

           System.out.println(tst.get(i).getText());
           Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize i with 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= tst.size(); i++)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The list is 0 indexed which means it runs from 0 to lst.size()-1, change your for loop from

```
for (int i = 1; i<=tst.size(); i=i+1) //In your case, runs from 1 to 10(included)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i<tst.size(); i=i+1) //For your case, this runs from 0 to 9(included)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.

```
for(int i=0;i<=tst.size()-1;i++)
```

its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your sysout for tst.size(). Since the size is 10, I would have your loop changed to for (int i = 0; i

As per the Array concepts, the indexing starts from 0 instead of 1. Hence the above modification should satisfy your need.